# Java-Selenium : TakesScreenshot size issue

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have created 'takescreenshot' reusable method to capture screenshot and have been calling wherever I need it.

however I am facing one strange issue here. Every time this function is called the captured image size keeps increasing 
e.g 252K -> 278K -> 310K -> 400K ...

These captured images I am using in ExtentReport. Also apart from selenium session image, I do see a black background image being captured not sure where it is coming from.

method code is as below:

```
public static void takescreenshot(ExtentTest Test,String Status){
    Date d=new Date();
    String CurrentTimeStamp=d.toString().replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_");

    File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(CurrentTimeStamp+".png"));

    if(Status.equals("pass")){
        Test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "snapshot below:-"+CurrentTimeStamp+".png"));


    }else if(Status.equals("fail")){    
        Test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "snapshot below:-"+CurrentTimeStamp+".png"));

    }
}
```

if I hardcode some existing image in extentreport code then everything works fine.

Has anyone come across this issue ever.

Comment: `if I hardcode some existing image in extentreport code then everything works fine.` - you almost got it, I think. Most likely, the issue is in how the image is being used. I do not see any issues in `takescreenshot` method itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had written a code to capture screenshot of elements which works fine. May be this will help you. I don't know what Extendreport is, so can't help you there.

```
  public static void takeElementScreenshot(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
            try{

                // Get entire page screenshot
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

                // Get the location of element on the page
                Point point = element.getLocation();

                // Get width and height of the element
                int eleWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
                int eleHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();

                // Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
                BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
                    eleWidth, eleHeight);
                ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

                // Copy the element screenshot to disk
                File screenshotLocation = new File("D:\\Screenshot.png");
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                } 
        }
```

Comment: I may not get the webelement incase of failed scenario, so in that case how do get the element location

Comment: Ah, in that case, the above code won't work. It expects a WebElement as argument. In your case, may be you have to crop the desired element from the fullpage by using some other logic other than using element's location.